# How to get MvcScaffold to work with external models?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, scaffolding

Steve Sanderson has a great blog that goes into the details of MvcScaffolding.  See it here http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2011/01/13/mvcscaffolding-standard-usage/

He also has a great video on http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/mvcConf/mvcConf-2-Steve-Sanderson-MvcScaffolding

In his blog he mentions….
*ModelType : By default we try to infer this from the controller name, but if you want your controllers and models to have totally unrelated names, you can specify a particular model type using this parameter. We’ll find any model class defined in your project or another project it references, but not in any external assembly.*

Our ViewModels are kept in a separate project in the same solution.   However we are Referencing the DLL so Get-ProjectType –ModelType ourVM –Project OurProject does not find the model.
No problem it is an open source project.   I will down the code and tweek Get-ProjectType.

I am unable to find where Get-ProjectType is defined in PowerShell. (resolved)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We used MvcScaffold to create custom Scaffolders ( see steve sanderson video during MvcConf 2). Then our custom scaffolder called our custom powershell scripts to do the work.